# HTML5 video: Modify http range request headers

Tags: javascript, html, video, http-headers

I have a html5 video player (video -tag). When the page loads it will send request to video file.

Is it possible to modify the http request headers Range field? (see the screenshot, between 2 red lines)

Range: bytes=0- 
will download whole video and I would like to limit it to "Range: bytes=0-1000000" for example

[image: Screenshot]

Video file is hosted on CDN, so I cant do anything on serverside.

Comment: I think most current browser implementations are fairly smart about this. When the video tag first came out, I remember that a tag would attempt to download the entire file as fast as possible. More recent versions seem to only pre-buffer a few seconds. Are you seeing a browser that is attempting to download the entire file on page load?

Comment: The problem is when you pause the video. Then browsers will start downloading the file as fast as possible

Comment: The browser should automatically reset the connection (aborting the transfer) when it is far enough ahead of what playback requires, and then request more starting at the last byte received if and when it needs more.

Comment: I thought it would work like that, but it doesn't. When you hit pause, the browser will start downloading the files as fast as possible like downloading a file

Comment: This still seems to be the way Chrome and IE10 handle HTML5 video :-/

Comment: I saw Chrome even nows first calls 0- range once you start playing video using video tag, which means trying to load all file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could send a range request with a XMLHttpRequest! and get a blob file on window.URL.createObjectURL, if the server 'Accept-Range: Bytes'. The video tag provides you with a lot of events and properties, so you always know what is buffered and where you are. Even though the user clicked the progress bar, pause or stop button. Because the video properties are time based compared to byte range you need some additional information from the video file called video metadata. I'd played with [Yamdi](http://yamdi.sourceforge.net/) to get a xml file of played time to file seek position ratio and to set the metadata at the beginning for a .flv.

On server side read the range header (bytes=number1-number2...), open the video file, seek to number1, print (number2-number1+1) bytes and send some specific headers: Content-Type, Content-Disposition, HTTP/1.1 206 Partial Content, Content-Range.

You should follow the seek position. The length is up to you.

Comment: Loaded entire video into a blob, set video.src to the blob.  Chrome/Android still does not play it.  Also tried sending the blob a gzip as Chrome/Android request headers send a request for gzip

Comment: If anyone has a blob not playing then they should try `video.load()` before `video.play()`.